# Seaching multi-dimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to search a multi-dimensional array without having to loop through the elements.

I've done some reading and found [this on the `array_search` user contributed notes section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635) which seems to be exactly what I need but it requires ***PHP 5.5.0*** and above because it uses [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

> in (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) you don't have to write your own function to
>   search through a multi dimensional array
>
> ex :
>
> ```
> $userdb=Array (
>   (0) => Array
>     (
>       (uid) => '100',
>       (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
>       (url) => 'urlof100'
>     ),
>
>   (1) => Array
>     (
>       (uid) => '5465',
>       (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
>       (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
>     ),
>
>   (2) => Array
>     (
>       (uid) => '40489',
>       (name) => 'Michael',
>       (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
>     )
> );
> ```
>
> simply u can use this
>
> ```
> $key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
> ```

How do I replicate this functionality that is compatible with ***PHP 5.4.4*** and above? I could always just fall back to looping through the array but I want it to be a bit more efficient than that.

Comment: The point is that `foreach` with a `break` when value found is __more efficient__ than the code you provided.

Comment: Speaking strictly regarding the performance part. Unless you're searching a stupidly large array, any performance impact is negligible.

Comment: @u_mulder Oh it is? I'm fairly clueless with code efficiencies so pardon the ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew My dataset only has ~150 elements. I'll probably just loop through it then. Thank you!

Comment: If you did want to use this, there are several backwards compatible versions of array_column in the comments on the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: @uom-pgregorio as a very general rule of thumb, slow websites are nearly always caused by database bottlenecks. Databases are also the hardest part of a system to change, so always be sure to get that right from the start. Other than that, only do performance optimization when benchmark testing tells you to.

Comment: @iainn Cool, I should have taken a look first before I posted a question. Thanks!

Comment: @Goose Thanks for the info! In this case I'm trying to map countries from 2 different systems and one is from Oracle while the other is from MySQL. Since I can't join them from the database side I'm doing the join through PHP.

Comment: Well then, post a question with samples from the DBs and what you have tried.  There is undoubtedly a better way than using `array_search` to join these.